# Scala Type classes and don't work well with inheritence

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I currently program some classes which implement type classes. I use cats for this purpose. In this setting, I have classes `A[T]` and `B[T] <: A[T]`. `A[T]` is a monad, so when importing the right libraries, I can write

```
val x: A[Int] = ???
x.flatMap(_)
```

but I can't write

```
val x: B[Int] = ???
b.flatMap(_)
```

as scala doesn't find the flatMap operator.
Instead, I have to write

```
val x: B[Int] = ???
(b: A[Int]).flatMap(_)
```

for this to work. This is awkward as I expect subclasses to inherit the methods of superclasses.

For completeness, I add a minimal example without dependencies which shows the issue. In this, `Filterable` is a typeclass, that is implemented by `S`.

```
object StackOverflowTest {
  class S[+T]

  class Q[+T] extends S[T]

  trait Filterable[F[+_]] {
    def filter[A](x: F[A]): F[A]
  }

  implicit class FilterOps[F[+_], A](y: F[A])(implicit ev: Filterable[F]) {
    def filter: F[A] = ev.filter(y)
  }

  implicit object SIsFilterable extends Filterable[S] {
    def filter[A](x: S[A]): S[A] = x
  }

  //def failing = {
  //  val q = new Q[Int]()
  //  val r = q.filter
  //}

  def working = {
    val q = new Q[Int]()
    val r = (q: S[Int]).filter
  }
}
```

The `failing` definition doesn't compile, because `q.op` isn't found. On the other hand, `working` mitigates this issue by first casting to `S`. What can I do to make the `failing` example work for users of my library? It feels very unnatural that you have to cast to a parent type to be able to use a method of it.

Note, that I can't define a second implicit object which implements `Filterable[Q]` because `(new Q[Int]()).filter` should be of type `S[Int]` and not `Q[Int]`.

Comment: A similar problem is `Some` vs `Option`. This is why cats provides smart constructors for `Xor`, `Validated`, ... so you eg don't end up with `Validated.Valid[Int]` but with `Validated[Nothing, Int]`. Maybe it is possible to follow a similar strategy with `Q` ?

Comment: @PeterNeyens: unfortunately this strategy is not possible since Q has some additional functions I want to expose to the user

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `SIsFilterable` with:

```
implicit def sOrSubtypeIsFilterable [T[+_] <: S[_]] = new Filterable[T] {
  def filter[A](x: T[A]): T[A] = x
}
```

Comment: the return type of `filter` should be `S[A]`, then this seems to solve the problem indeed. I wonder if this also works together with cats; when adding this second implicit, I might get problems with ambiguous implicit definitions.

Comment: why should the return be `S[A]`? Don't you want the a filtered `Q[...]` to still be a `Q[...]`?

Comment: in my use case `filter` is a little bit more complicated and can only return a `S[A]`